# include externals in subversion diff

Tags: svn, version-control, diff, svn-externals

I have setup my project in SVN to use an external library.
When I want to push some modifications to the live server I do a diff between versions and copy only the changed files. 
My problem is that the diff does not check the external modifications also, it just returns the project modifications.

What is your strategy to deploy modifications for projects with external code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a build tool ([Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)) for checking and updating the dependencies. Those are configured in build-scripts and stay on some server from where they are downloaded accoding to the config-files.